# Retrieve values from joomla component router.php

Tags: php, joomla, router, sef

ok i got my custom component router, but i still need the values inside it and i dont know how can i use these values in my component

for example in the url

index.php?option=com_maodeobras&view=maodeobras&cat=mymaincat&sub=mysubcat

i want the desired result (achieved with my router)

maodeobras/mymaincat/mysubcat.html

the question is:

how can i retrieve the variables cat and sub from the component or url?

here's my router

```
function MaodeobrasBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['view'])):
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    endif;

    if(isset($query['id'])):
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    endif;

    if(isset($query['cat'])):
        $segments[] = $query['cat'];
        unset($query['cat']);
    endif;

    if(isset($query['sub'])):
        $segments[] = $query['sub'];
        unset($query['sub']);
    endif;

    return $segments;
}

function MaodeobrasParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();

   $app =& JFactory::getApplication();
   $menu =& $app->getMenu();
   $item =& $menu->getActive();
    // Count segments
    $count = count($segments);
    //Handle View and Identifier
    switch($segments[0])
    {
        case 'maodeobras':
            //if ($count == 1) {
                $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
                $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                $vars['view'] = 'maodeobras';
            //}
            break;

        case 'categoriasdemãodeobras':
            $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
            $vars['view'] = 'categoriasdemãodeobras';
            break;
        case 'madeobrasfiltros':
            $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
            $vars['view'] = 'madeobrasfiltros';
            break;

        case 'subcategorias':
            $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
            $vars['view'] = 'subcategorias';
            break;
    }

    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, forget about all the trash that the component builders give u, and create your own router.php

heres the solution!
for a query:

index.php?option=com_maodeobras&cat=mymaincat&sub=mysubcat&Itemid=123

u gonna have a sef url like
/mymaincat/mysubcat.html

```
function MaodeobrasBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['cat'])):
        $segments[] = $query['cat'];
        unset($query['cat']);
    endif;

    if(isset($query['sub'])):
        $segments[] = $query['sub'];
        unset($query['sub']);
    endif;

    return $segments;
}

function MaodeobrasParseRoute($segments)
{
$vars = array();

   $vars['cat'] = $segments[0];
   $vars['sub'] = $segments[1];

    return $vars;
}
```

And to retrieve these values inside your view file, simple do this
echo JRequest::getVar('cat');
or 
echo JRequest::getVar('sub');

Thats All!!